# A Python dictionary of files - how?

Tags: python, file, dynamic, dictionary

I need to open some new csv files on the fly, depending on what data the infile contains. These csv files need to have filenames based on this data so they can't be hard coded.

I'm trying to make a dictionary of {filename,FILENAME.CSV}, and am having trouble with the lines below:

```
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        files_dict[filename] = open(filename,'w')
    files_dict[filename].write('Test')
```

The if statement works fine - it will happily go through the infile creating all the necessary csv files.

It doesn't like the write statement though:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "R:\DataTeam\Orange\Landline\Fixed\Websource_Landline_FixedData_SplitIntoAccounts_20110307.py", line 141, in <module>
    files_dict[filename].write('Test')
KeyError: 'OBS Fixed 6-65544 - BRICO DEPOT 201005.csv'
```

Any ideas on how to write to these files that have been successfully created? Or is there a much easier way to do this?

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: If the file already exists, it is not opened and not put into the dict.

Comment: If a file already exists, it would have been created by a previous iteration of these statements, so should already be in the dictionary and open ready for writing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem lies with the fact that if the file already exists, you are not opening the file  or assigning the filename as a key in the dict, hence the `KeyError` exception.

Try this instead:

```
# open file if not yet open
files_dict.setdefault(filename, open(filename,'w')) 
files_dict[filename].write("test")
```

This opens a file in write mode if the filename does not yet exist in the dict, and stores the handler in the dict with the filename as the key. Note that files that *already exists* but has not yet been assigned to the dict will be overwritten.

If you are only performing a single write, you can combine the lines since `setdefault` will return the value assigned to the key.

```
files_dict.setdefault(filename, open(filename,'w')).write("test")
```

Comment: I changed from checking if the file existed through os.file to just checking if it was in the dictionary, and this seemed to sort it. As per the comment above, the files would only be created by iterating through these statements previously, so I was confused why it wouldn't still be open and available for writing. Anyhow, it works now and I've learned something so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Shawn Chin's proposed solution does indeed remove the error, but it introduces a subtle bug: setdefault's 2nd parameter is a value, not a function called when needed; therefore, open(filename,'w') is called every time setdefault is called. This results in an additional file handle that may conflict with existing open handles in the same program, and it has a number of consequences discussed in "Effective Python: 90 Specific Ways to Write Better Python, 2nd Edition". The book provides a more sophisticated solution, but something simple like this may suffice:

```
if filename in files_dict:
    file = files_dict[filename]
else:
    file = open(filename,'w')
    files_dict[filename] = file
file.print("test")
```